# "not only a popular but also .." VS "a not only popular but also ..."

Tags: phrases

(1) It is not only a popular but also pragmatic research.
(2) It is a not only popular but also pragmatic research.

Which one is correct?

Comment: If you're using "...a popular...", you should also use "...a pragmatic...".

Comment: ...but _research_ is not usually a countable noun, so you would say _a piece of research_ or _a research project_ rather than _a research_.